# Создание файла c#

Tags: c#, winforms

Есть проблема. Создаю файл. На диск на котором запрещено создание чего либо. Этот запрет можно как то обойти из программы не выдавая локально себе на компьютере админских прав? Копмьютер домашний. Не чем дополнительным права не лочяться. Просто запрещено создавать что либо на диске c. Нужно создать вордовский файл. Можно как то запустить процесс создания файла от прав админа?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Без админских прав запрет записи обойти нельзя.
2. Можно запустить программу от другого пользователя, у которого есть админские права. Либо, если у тебя Win7+, дать админские права текущему пользователю, использовать UAC (тогда по умолчанию всё будет запускаться без админских прав) и в контекстном меню выбрать запуск с админскими правами.
3. Права файловой системы можно обойти привилегией [Backup Restore](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/aa387705(v=vs.85).aspx). Однако, чтобы задать эти привилегии, надо обладать админскими правами.

Comment: Спасибо за информацию.